# How to install django nonrel package

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-nonrel

When i am trying to install pip install "git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine
" i am getting an error

```
ERROR:root:Error while trying to get django settings module.
    Error was: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

And when running app getting this error

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.django_mongodb_engine' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named django_mongodb_engine.base
```

What to do.Help me if anyone know...

Comment: That first error isn't happening during the install. Please show exactly what you typed.

Comment: [root@localhost DBE]# pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine
Downloading/unpacking git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine
  Cloning https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine to /tmp/pip-gFKmxC-build
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-gFKmxC-build/setup.py) egg_info for package from git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine
    ERROR:root:Error while trying to get django settings module.
    Error was: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured

Comment: This is the reference i used http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html

Comment: Did you do the previous steps on that page? I notice for example that your prompt doesn't show you're running inside a virtualenv, even though the docs say to do so. (And please don't run as root, that's never a good idea.)

Comment: Thanks for giving reply,If i am not running as root,I am getting permissions denied...

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, Thanks boss,Its worked

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the first error is an pip install error.  The [mongodb-engine](https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine/blob/master/django_mongodb_engine/__init__.py) package has an odd dependency where it needs to insert itself as an 'app' in your django project.  For that reason it needs to know where the appropriate 'settings.py' is.

To do this, point the environment variable [DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/) to the appropriate 'settings.py'.  (Yes... its very weird that this is required during a pip install... again to understand why see [here](https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine/blob/master/django_mongodb_engine/__init__.py)).

As for the second error... assuming this is just a ripple from the mongodb-engine backend not being installed correctly in the first place.